# How to open Modal window on standard lightning detail page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds, modal, popup

I have created a lightning component (aura) for custom lookup and use that popup in the object detail page (used component in vf and put that vf page in object page layout).

[image]

How can we open this above modal window in the parent record (Object detail page) ?

```
<!-- Moadal Popup for showing the search window on press of lookup icon -->
<div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aura:id="TaskLookup" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open visibilityNO">
    <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <div class="slds-modal__header" style="padding-bottom:15px;">
            <button class="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button--icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick="{!c.HideTaskPopup}">
                <c:SVG class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--large" xlinkHref="{!$Resource.LightningIcons + '/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close'}"></c:SVG>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
            </button>
            <ui:inputText label="Activity Title" updateOn="keyup" change="{!c.keyPressController}" class="slds-lookup__search-input slds-input" value="{!v.SearchKeyWord}" placeholder="Search Activity..." />
            
        </div>
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
            <div class="slds-lookup__item--label slds-text-body--small">{!v.Message}</div>
            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table_fixed-layout">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
                        <th scope="col" width="35%"><span class="slds-truncate">Activity Title</span></th>
                        <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">Created Date</span></th>
                        <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">To Do Type</span></th>
                        <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">Digital Channel</span></th>
                        <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">Owner</span></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    
                    <!--Child component for showing the searched result -->
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.SearchedResult}" var="obj">
                        <c:Activity_customLookup_Child2 tsk="{!obj}" />
                    </aura:iteration></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-modal__footer">
            <ui:button label="Cancel" class="slds-button slds-button--brand" labelClass="label" press="{!c.HideTaskPopup}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: try this once, [lightning:overlayLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary)

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 tried but it gives me this error `This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {markup://lightning:overlayLibrary}`

Comment: Can you share that code?

Comment: `$A.createComponent("lightning:card",{"title" : "Dynamically Created Card",},                           function(this, status) {if (status === "SUCCESS") {var modalBody = this;                                   component.find('popuplib').showCustomModal({header: "Test Modal",                                       body: modalBody, showCloseButton: true,  closeCallback: function(ovl) {                                            console.log('Overlay is closing'); } }).then(function(overlay){                             console.log("Overlay is made"); }); } });`

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 just used the simple code to show modal on the parent record.